# Ansible Playbook with Variables?

Tags: bash, azure, ansible

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 in Azure vm

ansible 2.4.3.0

python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

azure-cli (2.0.27)

I have successfully created my first vm in azure using an Ansible Playbook.

Now, my question is this:  Can I use variables in the playbook for things like admin-password, vmname etc, so that I could, for instance, put a list of 10 machines I want to create in a file with the different names and their passwords, and then loop through and feed that info through the playbook command to the playbook.yml file?

I'm open to any way of doing this, and I'm aware that Ansible may already have an easier/normal way of doing it, I just don't know enough to google what I need.

EDIT:
Evidently my question is too broad.  I'll try and be more specific.  I looked at the link that Konstantin Suvorov left.  As I understand it, the method described does the inverse of what I'm after, by letting you assign variables to groups. And in the examples, to existing machines.

What I need is to be able to create vms, in the normal YAML style, but be able to have the process loop in some way so that it will create machines 1 thru 10 with all the same info, save for the machine name and the password.  The examples above seem to use the variables to assign the same info to multiple machines.

How Can I do this?  I'm mostly a bash scripter, so what I'd do is put name:password for each machine on multiple lines of a file, loop thru it and run the ansible-playbook command once per loop to create each machine, feeding in the variables somehow.  However, I have a feeling that there's a more efficient way, such that I run the command once and the command will create each machine with the variables/info that are coded (somehow) into the yaml file.  Is this specific enough?

FURTHER EDIT:
Thanks for putting me on the right track.  I have adapted the script i used to create one vm to try to make it create two.  I am getting assorted errors, none of which seem to actually point to offending code.  Here follows what I'm trying:

```
- name: Create Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  with_items:
    - { vmname: 'testvmfordb', userpassword: 'my password' }
    - { vmname: 'testvmforfe', userpassword: 'my other password' }
  tasks:
  - name: Create virtual network inteface card
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      resource_group: my_rg
      name: "{{ item.vmname }}NIC"
      virtual_network: my_rg
      subnet: default
      public_ip_name: "{{ item.vmname }}IP"
      security_group: my_firewall_rules
  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: my_rg
      name: "{{ item.vmname }}"
      vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
      location: EastUS
      admin_username: myusername
      admin_password: "{{ item.userpassword }}"
      ssh_password_enabled: true
      storage_container: vhds
      storage_blob: "{{ item.vmname }}osdisk.vhd"
      network_interfaces: "{{ item.vmname }}NIC"
      image:
        offer: UbuntuServer
        publisher: Canonical
        sku: '16.04-LTS'
        version: latest
      os_type: Linux
```

Thanks in advance!

I followed @KonstantinSuvorov suggestion and separated the creation tasks in a separate file.  I got this message:

```
TASK [include_tasks] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/user/ansible_playbooks/azure_create_many_vms.yml:5
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "reason": "included task files must contain a list of tasks"
}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "reason": "included task files must contain a list of tasks"
}
```

Here's the files/code:
azure_create_many_vms.yml

```
- name: Create Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: azure_create_many_vms_tasks.yml
    with_items:
      - { vmname: 'testvmforelastic', userpassword: 'my user password' }
      - { vmname: 'testvmforfe', userpassword: 'my user password' }
```

azure_create_many_vms_tasks.yml

```
  tasks:
  - name: Create virtual network inteface card
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      resource_group: my_core_rg
      name: "{{ item.vmname }}NIC"
      virtual_network: my_core_rg
      subnet: default
      public_ip_name: "{{ item.vmname }}IP"
      security_group: my_core_firewall_rules
  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: my_core_rg
      name: "{{ item.vmname }}"
      vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
      location: EastUS
      admin_username: adminuser
      admin_password: "{{ item.userpassword }}"
      ssh_password_enabled: true
      storage_container: vhds
      storage_blob: "{{ item.vmname }}osdisk.vhd"
      network_interfaces: "{{ item.vmname }}NIC"
      image:
        offer: UbuntuServer
        publisher: Canonical
        sku: '16.04-LTS'
        version: latest
      os_type: Linux
```

Comment: yes, you can do that

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#host-variables

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I edited my question to clarify what I'm after.  Your link was good, but read what I've added to the question please :)

Comment: Sorry, but there is still no specific question. You have to look through Ansible documentation, get familiar with variables, loops, lookups.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov is this better?

Comment: Yes. As soon as question is reopened, someone will place an answer: separate all vm creation tasks in a separate file and apply `with_items` to include statement. (you can't use it playbook-wide as you try to do in the example).

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I updated the question with the new errors and the updated code that generated them.  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `tasks` keyword from included file, leave just a plain list of tasks like this:

```
- name: Create virtual network inteface card
  azure_rm_networkinterface:
    ...
- name: Create VM
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    ...
```

Comment: That did it, it works great.  Now, on to more fancier things:  Is there a way to make this spawn each vm creation asyncronously?  I mean it's nice to run it as a batch, but is it possible to have multiple creation tasks run simultaneously?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but code should be refactored. Remove task loop. Then every vm should be defined as separate entry in the inventory with its own vars (like `vmname`) and playbook should be executed with `hosts: all`. This way Ansible will execute creation task for each vm in parallel.